# Table of numbers in a pattern using PHP

Tags: php, for-loop, html-table, nested

A couple of days ago, I made a post similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46197415/pattern-output-stuck).

I continued my work, but went back to this exercise after.

I need 2 more patterns in a **table**. The last 2 tables, I did with **nested For-loops**, which worked excellent, but now I'm stuck again.

What I need:

> 1 
>                  2 1 
>               3 2 1 
>            4 3 2 1 
>         5 4 3 2 1 
>      6 5 4 3 2 1

What I tried:

```
<table>
        <b>Patroon III</b>
        <?php
            $rows = 6;
            for($row = 1; $row <= $rows; $row++){
                echo "<tr>";
                for($col = 6; $col >= $row; $col--){
                    if($col <= $row){ 
                        echo "<td class='td2'>" . $col . "</td>";
                    }
                    else {
                        echo "<td class='td2'>" . " " . "</td>";
                    }
                }
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        ?>
</table>
```

What I get:

> 1 
>                  2 
>               3 
>            4 
>         5 
>      6

And the second table I need:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6
>      2 3 4 5 6
>         3 4 5 6
>            4 5 6
>               5 6
>                  6

What I tried:

```
<table>
    <b>Patroon IV</b>
    <?php
        $rows = 6;
        for($row = 1; $row <= $rows; $row++){
            echo "<tr>";
            for($col = 1; $col <= $row; $col++){
                if($col >= $row){ 
                    echo "<td class='td2'>" . $col . "</td>";
                }
                else {
                    echo "<td class='td2'>" . " " . "</td>";
                }
            }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

What I get:

> 1
>      2
>         3
>            4
>               5
>                  6

Any suggestions? I'm thinking about another nested for-loop, but I don't know where to start. Not sure if the if-else statement is needed.

Comment: Is this your assignment?

Comment: mostly homework, but i try to do some for myself too

Comment: You should attempt to learn basic loop functionality first. Try to solve this with two loops with pen and paper. You already have half of the answer from your previous problem.

Comment: @BunkerBoy Assignment and homework is the same thing.

Comment: so @Emielh you should do it your self

Comment: well, that's what i tried, been stuck here for quite some time now. I dont need an answer, but i do need a big hint

Comment: take a look at this (https://codescracker.com/cpp/program/cpp-program-print-star-pyramid-patterns.htm) first. Learn how the for loop works and then only you will be able to make the pyramids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the very basic thing in php. You just need to think about the logic. That's it.

Here is your solution to your question

```
<b>Patroon III</b>
<table border=1>

        <?php
            $rows = 6;
            for($row = 1; $row <= $rows; $row++){
                echo "<tr>";
                for($col = 6; $col >= 1; $col--){
                    if($col <= $row){ 
                        echo "<td class='td2'>" . $col . "</td>";
                    }
                    else {
                        echo "<td class='td2'>" . " " . "</td>";
                    }
                }
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        ?>
</table>
<b>Patroon IV</b>
<table border=1>
    <?php
        $rows = 6;
        for($row = 1; $row <= $rows; $row++){
            echo "<tr>";
            for($col = 1; $col <= $rows; $col++){
                if($col >= $row){ 
                    echo "<td class='td2'>" . $col . "</td>";
                } else {
                    echo "<td class='td2'>" . " " . "</td>";
                }
            }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    ?>
</table>
```